# Most elegant isEmpty() Method for Binary Tree

Tags: java, is-empty

I'm trying to write the most elegant isEmpty() method for my LinkedBinaryTree class.

When the compiler interacts with the if statement, it should return a boolean value or either true of false. However, since it is necessary to return a value *outside* the if statement, I've returned a value of false. My logic is that if (count == 0), isEmpty() returns true and doesn't bother with the second line (return false). Is this correct?

```
public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTreeADT<T>
{
   protected int count;
   protected BinaryTreeNode<T> root; 

   /**
    * Creates an empty binary tree.
    */
   public LinkedBinaryTree() 
   {
      count = 0;
      root = null;
   }

   /**
    * Creates a binary tree with the specified element as its root.
    *
    * @param element  the element that will become the root of the new binary tree
    */
   public LinkedBinaryTree (T element) 
   {
      count = 1;
      root = new BinaryTreeNode<T> (element);
   }

   /**
    * Returns true if this binary tree is empty and false otherwise.
    *
    * @return  true if this binary tree is empty
    */
   public boolean isEmpty() 
   {
       if (count == 0);
       return false; 
   }
```

Comment: No, it isn't. `if` statements terminating with a semicolon just get ignored, your method will always return `false`. Also, `count`is useless in your context. It gets incremented to 1 when a root is defined, so you can just do `if(root == null) return true; else return false;`, or, shorter, `return root == null`

Comment: `if (count == 0);` technically does nothing. What are you trying to do. Maybe you just want `return count == 0;`?

Comment: You can return in an if statement. You also have to make sure that every path returns though, and it sounds like that is what was wrong.

Comment: "Is this correct?" -- you could find out by testing it.

Answer (score 2):

"Is this correct?" -- you could find out by testing it. I recommend you do so, ideally in a jUnit test:

```
 @Test
 public void isEmpty_returns_true_for_empty_list() {
     LinkedBinaryTree tree = new LinkedBinaryTree();
     assertTrue(tree.isEmpty());
 }
```

... and a similar test for a non-empty tree.

"Most elegant"?

I would go for one of:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return count == 0;
}
```

... or perhaps ...

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return root == null;
}
```

(Are you sure your implementation needs a `count` variable?)

---

Java, like C, allows you to omit the braces from an `if` statement. A common recommendation is to never omit the braces, because it's a cause of confusion.

What you have written is equivalent to:

```
 if(count == 0) {
 }
 return false;
```

So it always returns false.

You could write:

```
 if(count == 0) {
    return true;
 }
 return false;
```

Or without braces (not recommended):

```
 if(count == 0)
     return true;
 return false;
```

But since this is equivalent to `return count == 0`, it's inelegant to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip to use a Junit test. I'd never heard of it before. And by elegant I meant most concise (but you figured that out lol). Thanks for the response, I understand much more clearly :)

Comment: You're welcome. Do note however, that sometimes the most concise code isn't the most elegant (or we'd all be using one-character variable names).

Answer (score 0):

You can just return your condition without "**if**" statement

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return (count == 0);
```

}

Comment: You don't need the parentheses either.

Comment: Correct. In my opinion parentheses add to clarity of code (readability) but as far as the code goes it will work the same with or without them

Comment: @MichaelGantman They sure do, but with a single condition they are useless IMO... If you have more and/or you might add parentheses for clarity, but with just one condition it doesn't affect clarity :)